# Skype call recorder for Android

Tags: gratis, android, audio, skype

I need something for an Android phone (specifically a Galaxy S4) that allows me to record good quality audio of both sides of a Skype conversation. I'm not interested in the video component.

There are several possible candidates on the app store, but reviews are middling, and there seems to be a strong possibility they will not work. I don't really have the opportunity to test this, so I need something that works of the bat.

I'd prefer it to be free. But I don't mind spending a small amount on a professional app if it gives me confidence that it will get the job done.

Comment: Related post: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28444/can-i-record-a-skype-call-audio-and-voice-using-a-samsung-galaxy-s3

Comment: http://gizmostorm.com/how-to-record-skype-call-on-android-without-root/